# Tuning Parameters to Optimize Score without CNN

Tags: rust, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to create an Agent in Rust that uses a scoring function to determine the best move on a 2D uniform cost grid. The specifics of the game aren't very relevant, other than knowing that each turn you can choose to make one of 4 moves (up, down, left or right) and you are competing against other AIs who are playing on the same board. Currently the AI makes "branches" of possible paths it could make into the future using several different simple algorithms such as using A* to find enemies or food. Several characteristics are saved as the future simulations run including the number of enemies we killed on that branch, amount of food we ate and how long the future branch lasted before we died.

Once we are ready to make our move, we give each future predicting branch a score and go in the direction with the highest average score. This score is essentially a sum of each characteristic mentioned previously multiplied by a constant. For example the score may be `30 * number of food eaten + 100 * number of enemies killed`. However, the number 30 and 100 were chosen almost at random through experimentation. If the snake died from not eating food then I increase the score multiplier for eating food for example. However, there are 10 different characteristics each with their own weight. Figuring out the relationship between them all manually is both time consuming and doesn't easily converge onto the optimal strategy.

Here in lies my issue. I would like to find a way to "train" the values for the AI through a process sort of like Q-Learning. There is a very clear terminal condition when you win or lose which helps. My currently idea is creating a table with 100 possible values of each parameter, then play 100 games with each combination and record the win rate. However, this would take `(1000 choose 10) * 100` games or `2.6E25` games. It seems like there should be a smarted way to eliminate bad combinations using some form of loss minimization. If anybody has suggestions on tuning these parameters without a neural network, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any kind of optimization algorithm should work: gradient descent, simplex, …

Comment: Thank you @Jmb for your reply. My issue here is that I don't know how to apply linear regression to my situation. I assume I would use the same scoring function for the entire game and then tune the values based on whether I won or lost that game. However, what would my dependant variable be, the score the function creates or an assigned value from me winning or losing the game? Since I don't have a labeled dataset, I don't know what the loss was for the scoring function after each turn. My only measure of success is me either winning or loosing that game.